# odr function for fitting ODEs: formatting the np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ode, model-fitting

i found this code ( [Curve fitting to coupled ODEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640311/curve-fitting-to-coupled-odes) ) and would like to apply it to my example. however it have a system of 3 ODE instead one like in the example. i think i have formatted the the np array wrong at some point because i receive the error message:
'    raise OdrError("fcn does not output %s-shaped array" % y_s)

OdrError: fcn does not output [273]-shaped array'

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.odr import Model, Data, ODR

X0=np.array([1.88217580e+01,  6.39178479e+00,  2.17062151e+00,  7.37133388e-01,
        2.50327190e-01,  8.50099826e-02,  2.88690076e-02,  9.80376865e-03,
        3.32931467e-03,  1.13061872e-03,  3.83953088e-04,  1.30385145e-04,
        4.42782276e-05,  1.50356782e-05,  5.10477998e-06,  1.73382003e-06,
        5.89295908e-07,  2.00567131e-07,  6.90030549e-08,  2.57878131e-08,
        9.67160308e-09,  1.97119162e-09, -1.69012581e-09, -1.71545398e-09,
       -3.71472345e-10,  2.30848671e-10,  7.16248000e-11, -1.55728077e-10,
       -1.42665015e-10,  6.05398499e-12,  1.85058432e-10,  3.41362199e-10,
        3.88187908e-10,  3.51166400e-10,  2.65669133e-10,  1.60540390e-10,
        6.41768726e-11,  1.08933660e-11,  4.57027140e-12,  1.10891069e-11,
        2.56927243e-11,  2.78420609e-11,  1.18751279e-11, -3.62281809e-12,
       -8.46085327e-12, -1.39074100e-12,  4.91246015e-12,  7.30936087e-12,
        1.32752431e-12, -3.13381780e-12, -8.11612234e-12, -1.00280844e-11,
       -5.53945281e-12, -1.01747651e-13,  2.04901659e-12,  1.13451885e-12,
       -9.04619801e-13, -1.84246991e-12, -9.54025800e-13,  2.78887763e-13,
        1.14911302e-12,  6.48264819e-13, -3.46980469e-14, -6.75972274e-13,
       -6.37761429e-13, -3.82725056e-13,  1.36698883e-13,  6.92178214e-13,
        6.53658276e-13,  5.49382735e-13,  1.80455683e-13, -2.33472724e-13,
       -3.00186786e-13, -3.11933704e-13, -1.37129091e-13,  1.13089169e-13,
        1.79605942e-13,  3.01644773e-13,  2.48001098e-13,  8.43594772e-14,
       -2.49816805e-14,  2.30314000e-14,  1.47890730e-14,  3.08335407e-14,
        8.00840951e-14,  1.20170440e-13,  1.20712574e-13,  1.31143818e-13,
        1.30834746e-13,  1.00040346e-13,  4.87840502e-14])
Xp=np.array([0.        , 3.74954652, 5.54244266, 6.0479111 , 6.11417888,
       6.03392821, 5.90652069, 5.76563354, 5.62263923, 5.48133732,
       5.34295714, 5.20785681, 5.07610002, 4.94765199, 4.8224459 ,
       4.70040546, 4.58145249, 4.46550957, 4.3525007 , 4.24235175,
       4.13499035, 4.03034588, 3.9283496 , 3.82893457, 3.73203547,
       3.6375886 , 3.5455319 , 3.45580487, 3.36834858, 3.28310554,
       3.20001976, 3.11903664, 3.04010298, 2.96316691, 2.88817786,
       2.81508655, 2.74384496, 2.67440629, 2.60672491, 2.54075635,
       2.47645726, 2.41378539, 2.35269956, 2.29315964, 2.23512649,
       2.17856199, 2.12342898, 2.06969122, 2.01731341, 1.96626112,
       1.91650082, 1.8679998 , 1.82072621, 1.77464897, 1.72973781,
       1.68596322, 1.64329643, 1.60170942, 1.56117485, 1.5216661 ,
       1.48315719, 1.44562283, 1.40903836, 1.37337973, 1.33862352,
       1.30474688, 1.27172757, 1.23954388, 1.20817466, 1.1775993 ,
       1.14779772, 1.11875033, 1.09043804, 1.06284225, 1.03594484,
       1.00972811, 0.98417486, 0.95926828, 0.93499202, 0.91133011,
       0.88826703, 0.8657876 , 0.84387706, 0.82252101, 0.80170542,
       0.78141661, 0.76164125, 0.74236635, 0.72357923, 0.70526757,
       0.68741932])
Xc=np.array([0.        , 1.80507171, 0.66166362, 0.25919594, 0.12154879,
       0.07395521, 0.05696567, 0.05039004, 0.04737134, 0.04558043,
       0.04422586, 0.04303835, 0.04192599, 0.04085709, 0.03982044,
       0.0388118 , 0.03782928, 0.03687183, 0.03593868, 0.03502916,
       0.03414267, 0.03327862, 0.03243643, 0.03161556, 0.03081546,
       0.03003561, 0.0292755 , 0.02853462, 0.0278125 , 0.02710864,
       0.0264226 , 0.02575392, 0.02510217, 0.02446691, 0.02384772,
       0.02324421, 0.02265596, 0.0220826 , 0.02152376, 0.02097906,
       0.02044814, 0.01993066, 0.01942627, 0.01893465, 0.01845547,
       0.01798842, 0.01753318, 0.01708946, 0.01665698, 0.01623545,
       0.01582458, 0.0154241 , 0.01503376, 0.0146533 , 0.01428247,
       0.01392102, 0.01356872, 0.01322533, 0.01289064, 0.01256442,
       0.01224645, 0.01193653, 0.01163445, 0.01134001, 0.01105303,
       0.01077331, 0.01050067, 0.01023493, 0.00997591, 0.00972345,
       0.00947738, 0.00923754, 0.00900376, 0.0087759 , 0.00855381,
       0.00833734, 0.00812634, 0.00792069, 0.00772024, 0.00752486,
       0.00733443, 0.00714882, 0.0069679 , 0.00679157, 0.00661969,
       0.00645217, 0.00628888, 0.00612973, 0.0059746 , 0.0058234 ,
       0.00567603])

P=np.array([X0,Xc,Xp])    
tmax, Nt = 90, int(90)
# Times at which the solution is to be computed.
t = np.linspace(0, tmax, Nt+1)


def coupledODE(beta, x):
    ka,Cltp,Clpt,Cl = beta


    # Three coupled ODEs
    def conc (y, t) : 
        X0=-ka*y[0]
        Xc=ka*y[0]+Cltp*y[2]-Clpt*y[1]- Cl*y[1]
        Xp=Clpt*y[1]-Cltp*y[2]
        f= np.array([X0,Xc,Xp])
        return f


    # Initial conditions for y[0], y[1] and y[2]
    y0 = np.array([X0[0],Xc[0], Xp[0]])



    # Solve the equation
    y = odeint(conc, y0, x)

    #return y[:,1]
    # in case you are only fitting to experimental findings of ODE #1
    print('y1',y.shape)
    y=y.ravel()
    print('y2',y.shape)
    return y

    # in case you have experimental findings of all three ODEs

#data = Data(t, P)
# with P being experimental findings of ODE #1

data = Data(np.repeat(t, 3), P.ravel())
# with P being a (3,N) array of experimental findings of all ODEs

model = Model(coupledODE)
#guess = [0.1,0.1,0.1]
guess = [0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15]

odr = ODR(data, model, guess)
odr.set_job(2)
out = odr.run()
print(out.beta)
print(out.sd_beta)

f = plt.figure()
p = f.add_subplot(111)
p.plot(t, P[0], 'ro')
p.plot(t, coupledODE(out.beta, t))
plt.show()
```

Any help with this issue would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of ODR is not very forthcoming in the non-scalar case, but in the end it is quite logical.

The purpose of the ODR sub-package is to fit a function *`y=f(b,x)`* to a given data set of argument-value pairs `(x[k], y[k])`, `k in range(n)`. As part of this the function needs to be repeatedly evaluated on the full input data set for different parameters `b`, thus `f` has to primarily support a "vectorized" evaluation.

The model function *`f`* thus takes an *`n`* long input *`x`* for a scalar domain in *`n`* samples, or an array with shape *`(m,n)`* for input vectors with *`m`* components. Similarly the output *`y`* has to be an array of length *`n`* for scalar output or of shape *`(q,n)`* for vector output.

While the *`n`* has to be the same in all instances, *`m`* and *`q`* are independent. In the present case, *`m=1`* and *`q=3`*, that is, the input is scalar.

The script has thus to be corrected to remove all flattening operations, there need to be some transpositions as the result of **`odeint`** has shape *`(n,3)`*, which is also the required format for the plot command to plot multiple lines in one go.

```
def coupledODE(beta, x):
    ka,Cltp,Clpt,Cl = beta

    # Three coupled ODEs
    def conc (y, t) : 
        X0=-ka*y[0]
        Xc=ka*y[0]+Cltp*y[2]-Clpt*y[1]- Cl*y[1]
        Xp=Clpt*y[1]-Cltp*y[2]
        f= np.array([X0,Xc,Xp])
        return f

    # Initial conditions for y[0], y[1] and y[2]
    y0 = np.array([X0[0],Xc[0], Xp[0]])

    # Solve the equation
    y = odeint(conc, y0, x)
    # Transpose from (N,q) to (q,N)
    return y.T

data = Data(t, P)
# with P being a (3,N) array of experimental findings of all ODEs

model = Model(coupledODE)
guess = [0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15]

odr = ODR(data, model, guess)
odr.set_job(2)
out = odr.run()
print(out.beta)
print(out.sd_beta)

f = plt.figure()
p = f.add_subplot(111)
t_plot = np.linspace(t[0],t[-1],300)
F = coupledODE(out.beta, t_plot).T
print(P.shape,F.shape)
p.plot(t, P.T, 'ro', ms=2)
p.plot(t_plot, F)
plt.show()
```

resulting in a parameter vector

```
[1.08       0.04       1.74       3.13000001]
```

and a picture with a visually good fit of the plots

[image: plot of the fit]